# Function names for anonymous functions in ES6

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

In ECMAScript 6 all functions have appropriate name:

```
console.log((function fn() {}).name); // 'fn'

console.log((new Function()).name); // 'anonymous'
```

But in case of anonymous function:

```
console.log((function () {}).name); // (empty string)
```

Can you explain, why we can't get output `'anonymous'` in case of third example?

Comment: it's in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createdynamicfunction) - if you search for "CreateDynamicFunction" in the spec, you'll see when the `name` is assigned `anonymous`

Comment: And anonymous functions inherit from the prototype, whose name is an empty string. [link](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function-instances-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMA-262 explicitly states the for functions created using the Function constructor that the name is set to "anonymous", see [Runtime Semantics: CreateDynamicFunction(*constructor, newTarget, kind, args*)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-createdynamicfunction) step 29.

However, that isn't the case for functions created using a function expression without an optional name (or binding a name in some other way), in that case the name must be left as the empty string.

Consoles try to be helpful, but in this case, changing "" to "anonymous" might be misleading.